# Send file by xmodem or kermit protocol with GNU screen

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port, kermit

I work with an RS-232 device via GNU `screen`.

```
$ screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

At some point I need to send a local file to the device using either the `xmodem` or `kermit` protocol. On Windows I use TeraTerm which has a corresponding menu item. How can I achieve this in GNU screen?

Answer (score 34):

the best way to pass a file through xmodem is to use `sx`. In debian this application is part of 'lrzsz' package.

In debian:

```
apt-get install screen lrzsz

screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> followed by <kbd>:</kbd> and type:

```
exec !! sx yourbinary.bin
```

This will send the file to ttyUSB0 over xmodem protocol

Comment: Can this operation be executed non-interactively, either with `screen` `cu` or any other package?

Comment: @Vorac you can always do `sx binary.bin | socat FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,b115200,raw -`

Comment: How to give receive command `Give your local XMODEM receive command now`

Comment: Where is that package maintained? I can't find it.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use zmodem you have to set the [`zmodem`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=screen&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) option to `pass`, if your screen session is already running, press <kbd>CTRL+A :</kbd> and just enter `zmodem pass` . To send the data just use the `sz` command from the `lrzsz` package.

If you want to receive data via screen you have to set the value to `catch`.

Comment: `zmodem catch` is an option I've been search for for ages! Good riddance, minicom.

Answer (score 5):

I was in need to automate the serial transfer of a .bin file to an xbee with xmodem so I used this sloppy bash code:

```
echo "Starting connection..."
screen -d -m -S uart_con /dev/ttyO1 115200
sleep 1
screen -S uart_con -X stuff 'F'$(echo -ne '\015')
sleep 1
screen -S uart_con -X exec \!\! sz -X /home/file_directory/example.abs.bin
echo "now transfering... "
sleep 20
pkill screen
```

The third line sends a command to the other side(xbee) to start listening for a file transfer. So you are probably good with just:

```
screen -d -m -S uart_con /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
screen -S uart_con -X exec \!\! sz -X /path_to_file/example.file
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to do this through screen on OSX, you can follow the procedure laid out by user32704 with some small modifications. You will need to first build lrzsz from source, which can be found here:

https://ohse.de/uwe/releases/lrzsz-0.12.20.tar.gz

Then, instead of `exec !! sx yourbinary.bin` you should use:

```
exec !! lsz -X yourbinary.bin
```

Comment: brew install lrzsz

Comment: `sudo port install lrzsz`

Answer (score 1):

Quoting AltairClone.com Using “screen” as terminal emulator under UNIX/LINUX https://altairclone.com/downloads/Using%20SCREEN%20as%20terminal%20emulator.pdf :

"

**Using “screen” as terminal emulator under UNIX/LINUX**

To start a session, type “screen” followed by the serial device name and baud rate:

```
Unix prompt> screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
```

To get to screen commands, type ctrl-a followed by a command character. To see a list of commands, type ctrl-a ? (no space after ctrl-a, ctrl is not held for ?).

To exit the current screen, type ctrl-a k

To exit all screens (if multiple started by mistake), type ctrl-a 
Some versions of screen may require ctrl-a ctrl-\

---

To send a file with XMODEM, type ctrl-a : (colon is the command character), then at the prompt, type:

```
exec !! sx [-a] filename
```

(Use –a to convert single new-line characters to CR/LF pairs.)

To receive a file with XMODEM, type ctrl-a : (colon is the command character), then at the prompt,
type:

```
exec !! rx [-a] filename
```

(Note: The first ! tells sx/rx to get stdin through screen’s input connection. The second ! tells sx/rx to
route stdout through screen’s output connection.)

To change the baud rate prior to an XMODEM transfer, type ctrl-a : (colon is the command character),
then at the prompt, type:

```
exec !! stty new_baud_rate
```

Alternatively, exit screen by typing ctrl-a k, then re-start screen at the new baud rate (e.g.):

```
Unix prompt> screen /dev/ttyUSB0 new_baud_rate
```

To simply send an ASCII or binary file (i.e., XMODEM not used), type ctrl-a : (colon is the command
character), then at the prompt, type:

```
exec !! cat filename
```

"